# Why my JS script operate only on my first instance of html object

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

I have this js script link to my html (found on the internet)

```
$(function() {
    var rangePercent = $('[type="range"]').val();
    $('[type="range"]').on('change input', function() {
        rangePercent = $('[type="range"]').val();
        $('h4').text(rangePercent);
        $('[type="range"]').css('filter', 'hue-rotate(-' + rangePercent*8 + 'deg)');
    });
});
```

i have serval instance of range input in my html.
Why this code only work with the first instance of "range" input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` will retrieve the value of *only* the first element in the jQuery collection. Also, `$('[type="range"]').css` will set the CSS of *all* elements that match that `[type="range"]` selector. Inside the callback, reference `this` instead, to reference the input that was changed:

```
$(function() {
    $('[type="range"]').on('change input', function() {
        const rangePercent = $(this).val();
        $('h4').text(rangePercent);
        $(this).css('filter', 'hue-rotate(-' + rangePercent*8 + 'deg)');
    });
});
```